# How to login to an ftp server using shell scripting in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, terminal, command

I want to login to my FTP server using shell scripting. I made a .sh file having contents as

ftp
open 172.31.1.45

but it's not working. The second command is not executing. Please help. I am new to linux so please forgive if this is a stupid question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST="yourhost"
USER="user"
PASSWD="pass"
FILE="file.txt"
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: how to put multiple files, i tried using mput * , but it is not wokring

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a matter of simple file transfers, you might want to look at using a tool like ncFTP, wget, or cURL, which can do file transfers in a single command.  Using these tools, you can simply pass the username, password, host address, source file, and destination file in one command.