# how to use data variable in mkdir in a linux server with FTP?

Tags: php, linux, ftp, mkdir

I need to create a folder in my FTP server, whose name is "YYYY-MM-DD"; I have this variable:

```
slideshow=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

but I can not use it in FTP with mkdir, since it's a shell variable.

I've also tried with echo, and there it works (I have "mkdir 2015-05-25" in a sh file), but if I have a series of commands that have to be run, just the first ftp -n ftp.xxxx.it. is run, the rest (user, password) isn't.

I hope you could help me,

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are shelling out to an ftp client instead of using a proper [ftp library](http://php.net/ftp).

Comment: You have to create a temporary `ftp` script dynamically in the shell script, using the variable and only then execute it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers: how could I do that? With what bash script?

Comment: so you are doing ftp from a php page? the ftp server you are connecting to, is on a different machine or is it on the same server? the question is not well written. or do you want help to write a bash script for linux in order to do FTP? i suggest you to use the #!/usr/bin/expect for the script.

Comment: Why are you not using ftp library as it is suggested by @Quentin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this script seems to be like this topic [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747345/how-to-login-to-an-ftp-srever-using-shell-scripting-in-linux)

but you can do it easily  by mkdir a new directory on your pc then upload it to your server by this simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Your Server credentials

```
ftp_server='******' 
ftp_username='******' 
ftp_password='******'
```

New folder with date in year with month and day

```
slideshow="`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`" 
new_folder=`mkdir $slideshow`
```

Access Your Server via ftp then authenticate to your server

```
ftp -n $ftp_server <<END_SCRIPT 
quote USER $ftp_username  
quote PASS $ftp_password
```

Upload your new created folder

```
put $new_folder
```

then quit

```
quit  
END_SCRIPT
```

full script

```
#!/bin/bash

ftp_server='********'
ftp_username='********'
ftp_password='********'
slideshow="`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`"
new_folder=`mkdir $slideshow`

ftp -n $ftp_server <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $ftp_username
quote PASS $ftp_password
put $new_folder
quit
END_SCRIPT
```