# Need to create a simple script for ftp login

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, backup, switching

I am planning to make a simple script for logging on to a switch & take the configuration backup!

I used to login manually & want to do this in a single command or through a script!

Anyone could help me out?

```
root@xxx:/home# ftp xxx.19.254.61
Connected to xxx.19.254.61.
220 xx-xx-xx-xxx-SW-2 FTP version 1.0 ready at Sat Feb 14 23:28:25 1970
Name (xxx.19.254.61:root): admin
331 Enter PASS command
Password:
230 Logged in
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> get config config.cfg
local: config.cfg remote: config
200 Port command okay
150 Opening data connection for RETR config
226 File sent OK
2824 bytes received in 1.05 secs (2.6227 kB/s)
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye!
```

Comment: See if `heredoc` can help you...

Answer (score 0):

Is [`heredoc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) not good for you?

```
$ ftp xxx.19.254.61 <<< EOF
get config config.cfg
bye
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's possible to add any destination path? So, that config data will save automatically over there!

Comment: I haven't used ftp. I think, you would have to first `cd` or `pushd` to the local directory, before your run the `get` command.

Comment: I think few thing needs to be edited. Like need to add lines for username, password invoke & destination path.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436493/how-to-use-data-variable-in-mkdir-in-a-linux-server-with-ftp)

```
ftp_server='localhost'
ftp_username='********'
ftp_password='***********'    
mkdir /home/user/linux/source_folder
source_folder="/home/user/linux/source_folder/"
cp -avr config* $source_folder
dest_folder="/home/user/linux/linux2/"
ftp -i -n $ftp_server <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $ftp_username
quote PASS $ftp_password
cd $source_folder
!cd $dest_folder
mget -R *
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

(Note: you should `mkdir` because ftp not support multiple file copies from source to destination folder so you should use mget with -R option to multiple files which located in new created directory then copy your config files to this new created directory with `cp -avr config* $source_folder`).

> this is another more enhanced script that no one can see your stored 
>   password, allowed to openssl encryption, decryption with pair keys .

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter Username: " Username
read -sp "Enter Username Password: " Password
echo
ftp_server="localhost"
ftp_username="$Username"
ftp_password="$Password"
passwrd=`echo $ftp_password | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt`
decrypt=`echo $passwrd | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt`
mkdir /home/username/linux/source_folder
source_folder="/home/username/source_folder/"
cp -avr config* $source_folder
dest_folder="/home/username/linux/dest_folder/"
ftp -in $ftp_server <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $ftp_username
quote PASS $decrypt
cd $source_folder
!cd $dest_folder
mget -R *
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

**instructions :**

- Enter Your Real Username
- Enter Your Real Password
- Encrypt Your private key
- Verify Password private key
- Last Login with the same private key

*Example :*

- Sazzad (Username)
- Sazzad (Real Password)
- P@$$w0rd (password_to_encrypt (private key))
- P@$$w0rd same password_to_encrypt (private key)
- P@$$w0rd same password_to_decrypt (private key)

**Note:**

you can delete those lines if you don't want pair key encryption with openssl connection

> passwrd=`echo $ftp_password | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt`
>
> decrypt=`echo $passwrd | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt`

and change `quote PASS $decrypt` to `quote PASS $ftp_password`

**Alternative:** 
Just Put Your `Username` and `Password` and `Server Ip` Like `172.19.254.61`

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter Username: " Username
read -sp "Enter Username Password: " Password
echo
read -p "FTP Server IP: " ftp_server
ftp_username=$Username
ftp_password=$Password
source_folder="/home/rr-de-nms-1/Sazzad/source_folder/"
cp -avr /home/rr-de-nms-1/Sazzad/config* $source_folder
dest_folder="/home/rr-de-nms-1/Sazzad/dest_folder/"
ftp -in $ftp_server <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $ftp_username
quote PASS $decrypt
cd $source_folder
!cd $dest_folder
mget -R *
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Now Your Config Files downloaded here in `/home/rr-de-nms-1/Sazzad/dest_folder/`

Comment: thanks for the reply. But could you please add Switch login command also in your script? It would be best for me to understand.

Comment: @SazzadHussein check latest script again bro

Comment: thank you very much for your effort & sorry for my late reply. I just have tried your script without encryption.
root@xxxx:/home/sabuj# ./test1.sh 
Enter Username: admin
Enter Username Password: 
cp: cannot stat â€˜config*â€™: No such file or directory
User  cannot log in.
No control connection for command: Bad file descriptor

Comment: I have edited your script like this:
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter Username: " admin
read -sp "Enter Username Password: " xxxxx
echo
ftp_server="172.19.xxx.xx"
ftp_username="$Username"
ftp_password="$Password"
passwrd=`echo $ftp_password
decrypt=`echo $passwrd
mkdir /home/sabuj/source_folder
source_folder="/home/sabuj/source_folder"
cp -avr config* $source_folder
dest_folder="/home/sabuj/dest_folder/"
ftp -in $ftp_server <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $ftp_username
quote PASS $ftp_password
cd $source_folder
!cd $dest_folder
mget -R *
quit
END_SCRIPT

Comment: @SazzadHussein no such file or directory because you didn't put a a config files location for example if your config files inside your home directory in this case `cp -avr /home/Sazzad/config $source_folder` .

Comment: would please check this link? I have uploaded required log here. I hope that helps you to dig more relevant information. I guess i am making very silly mistake & that's breaking everything. Expecting your help!https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ooCAjhwTkXZVRRRXprd3lpSW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SazzadHussein Check my answer again bro Alternative one don't edit anything and it should work plz feedback me you are welcome bro .

Comment: I have updated log here. Do you think the "config" file is ok? Thanks a lot bro for your co-operation! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ooCAjhwTkXZVRRRXprd3lpSW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SazzadHussein hello bro plz change this line `read -p "172.19.254.61" ftp_server` to `ftp_server="172.19.254.61"` and allow home dir ftp on selinux to be allowed try `setsebool ftp_home_dir 1` to allow access your ftp server because you won't be able to access ftp if `selinux` is enable or `enforced` feedback me and feel free to ask more you are welcome .

Comment: bro, please have a look over my setsebool status. I guess its already been allowed... Please click on the same link for updated log.

Comment: @SazzadHussein yeah its in permissive mode but you should restart to take effects could u plz type getsebool -a | grep ftp then check ftp_home_dir is on or off ?